# shinyCaptcha. How to customize my own button?

Tags: r, shiny, recaptcha

The example code for shinyCaptcha documentation works well.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyCAPTCHA)

ui <- fluidPage(
  recaptchaUI("test", sitekey = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"),
  uiOutput("body")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  result <- callModule(recaptcha, "test", secret = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe")
  
  output$body <- renderUI({
    fluidPage(
    uiOutput("humansOnly")
    )
    
  })  
  
  output$humansOnly <- renderUI({
    req(result()$success)
    tags$h1("For human eyes only!")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It shows:

[image]

The app includes the button and I cannot change it. I want to use my own button, change the label, the location, etc. is there any way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of `recaptchaUI` is:

```r
recaptchaUI <- function(id, sitekey = Sys.getenv("recaptcha_sitekey"), ...) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(tags$div(
    ......,
    tags$form(
      class = "shinyCAPTCHA-form",
      action = "?",
      method = "POST",
      tags$div(class = "g-recaptcha", `data-sitekey` = sitekey, `data-callback` = I("shinyCaptcha")),
      tags$br(),
      tags$input(type = "submit", ...)
    )
  ))
}
```

The button corresponds to `tags$input(type = "submit", ...)`. As you can see, it takes the arguments given in the ellipsis `...`. So, to change the text displayed on the button, you can use the `value` attribute of the submit button like this:

```r
recaptchaUI(
  "test", 
  sitekey = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI",
  value = "the text you want"
)
```

To change the style (color etc), use the `style` attribute:

```r
recaptchaUI(
  "test", 
  sitekey = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI",
  value = "the text you want",
  style = "color: red; background-color: yellow;"
)
```

To change the location of the button, for example to move it to the right, you can use the CSS property `margin-left`:

```r
recaptchaUI(
  "test", 
  sitekey = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI",
  value = "the text you want",
  style = "color: red; background-color: yellow; margin-left: 50px;"
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Please check my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938283/nested-uioutput-with-shinycaptcha).