# nested uiOutput with shinyCaptcha

Tags: r, shiny, recaptcha

I need to use some nested uiOutputs:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyCAPTCHA)

ui <- fluidPage(uiOutput("bodyOut"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  result <- callModule(recaptcha, "test", secret = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe")
  
  output$bodyOut <- renderUI({       
    list(
      recaptchaUI("test", sitekey = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"),
      uiOutput("humansOnly"))
  })   
    
  output$humansOnly <- renderUI({
    req(result()$success)
    tags$h1("For human eyes only!")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This app shows "For human eyes only!" when I checked the captcha. (In addition, the button "Enviar" does not work)

[image]

However, I need to trigger an event which valitades the captcha instead of use `output$humansOnly <- renderUI`. Something like this:

```
observeEvent(input$someid,{
   req(result()$success)
   output$humansOnly<-renderText("For human eyes only!")
   #Do some stuf
})
```

But I dont know what id to use. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I hope the `sitekey` and `secret` you posted are not your real ones!

Comment: Don't nest reactives and observers.  Instead, use your `observeEvent` simply to set some (reactive) text, based on the RECAPTCHA result.  Then define your `renderPrint` so that it displays your reactive text.  No need for `renderUI` here.  This is a great example of why it pays not to combine derivation of results with their display.  I think using `result()` instead of `input$someid` will trigger the actions you need.